# Time in a variable, decrease a delay

Tags: php

I have a time() value saved in a variable like this:

```
$latest_attempt = 1337980678;
```

I am trying to calculate some delay.

```
$remaining_delay = time() - $latest_attempt - $delay;
```

However the result of `$remaining_delay` is increasing when I update the browser, and not the way around.

"You must wait 95 seconds before your next login attempt"

If I update some seconds later "You must wait 102 seconds before your next login attempt"

It's doing the opposite what it should doing, instead it would rather decrease than increase. What have I done wrong? I believe I need to do something with latest_attempt variable, but I could not find anything i the php manual.

Comment: Your math is wrong: `($latest_attempt + $delay) - time()`

Comment: Yeah. `time()` is a positive value being added in your equation.  So as time() gets larger the result of your sum gets larger as well.  You need to be subtracting `time()` from something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say, something like this:

```
$remaining_delay = $latest_attempt + $delay - time();
```

Comment: You should probably explain why.

Comment: Well, that seems pretty trivial to me... `time` is always growing, so you need to subtract it from some constant value and not the opposite...

Answer (score 0):

```
$time_since_last = time() - $last_attempt;

if ($time_since_last <= $delay) {
    $remaining = $delay - $time_since_last;
} else {
   ... good to go ... delay's expired
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The remaining delay is the difference between that moment in time when the blockage expires (`$last_attempt + $delay` because from $last_attempt on, the user is blocked for a period of $delay) and the current time (`time()`) - therefore the correct formula is:

```
$remaining_delay = ($latest_attempt + $delay) - time();

if ($remaining_delay > 0) {
    die('Access denied, you need to wait another '. $remaining_delay .' seconds');
}
```